# get values of all checkboxes (checked or unchecked)with same name

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I am trying to build a form that lists all available items and users can select some items and enter a value to input element aside the checkbox.

Each checkbox has a input text box aside it.

```
<?php
    foreach ($items as $item):
        $itemID = $item['item_id'];
        $itemTitle = $item['item'];
?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <li> 
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input type="hidden" name="selected_items[]" value="0">
                    <input type='checkbox' name='selected_items[]' value='<?php echo $itemID; ?>'/> 
                <?php echo ucfirst($itemTitle); ?>

                </div>
            </li>
        </td>
        <td><input type='number' name='quantities[]' value="0.00" step="0.01" /> </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here's how the form looks:

```
Available Items    |  Qty
--------------------------
[] Bread           |  [input]
[] Coffee          |  [input]
[] Egg             |  [input]
[] Cake            |  [input]
```

I want the two arrays : `selected_items[]` and `quantities` to be of the same length as they are so I can combine them.

If unchecked, value should be left to 0.

So, combined_array should look like:

```
0=>0
Coffee=>44
Egg=>56
0=>0
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: looks like a task for javascript

Comment: Do you want your "combined_array" in `$_POST` data?

Comment: Also, you're "combined_array" would have duplicate keys, e.g. `0=>0`

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes do not show up in the form submission data set. Put an index into the brackets of the field names to begin with – `name='selected_items[0]'`, `name='selected_items[1]'` etc. and the same for the quantities - that will help you correlate the data that actually does get send appropriately. (The hidden field gets thrown out completely with this approach.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more detail, this example assumes you want the "combined_array" to set in your `$_POST` data...

Firstly I would remove the "hidden" `selected_items` input. As these are an array of inputs, the index keys would be out of alignment.

Setting the index key to a specific value for `selected_items`, `quantities` and adding a new input `item`, should help correlate your `$_POST` data like so:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item):
    $itemID = $item['item_id'];
    $itemTitle = $item['item'];
?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <li> 
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input type='checkbox' name='selected_items[<?php echo $itemID; ?>]' value='<?php echo $itemTitle; ?>'/>  <!-- Give your input $itemID key -->
                    <?php echo ucfirst($itemTitle); ?>
                </div>
            </li>
        </td>
        <td><input type='number' name='quantities[<?php echo $itemID; ?>]' value="0.00" step="0.01" /> </td>  <!-- Give your input $itemID key -->
    </tr>
    <input type='hidden' name='available_items[<?php echo $itemID; ?>]' value="<?php echo $itemTitle; ?>" />   <!-- Give your input $itemID value -->
<?php endforeach; ?>


<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    foreach($_POST['available_items'] as $itemID=>$itemTitle){ // <-- Loop through your "available_items"
        $itemTitle = (!empty($_POST['selected_items'][$itemID])?$itemTitle:0); // <-- this changes the itemTitle based on whether !empty($_POST['selected_items'][$itemID]) 
        $Qty = (!empty($_POST['selected_items'][$itemID])&&!empty($_POST['quantities'][$itemID])?$_POST['quantities'][$itemID]:0); // <-- Checks for quantities 
        $CombinedArray[$itemTitle] = $Qty;
    }
    print_r($CombinedArray);
}
?>
```

Your result would be something like this:

```
"0"=>0
"Coffee"=>44
"Egg"=>56
```

This is because you have the potential for creating duplicate keys in your `$CombinedArray`.

Removing this line `$itemTitle = (!empty($_POST['selected_items'][$itemID])?$itemTitle:0);`:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    foreach($_POST['available_items'] as $itemID=>$itemTitle){ // <-- Loop through your "available_items"
        $Qty = (!empty($_POST['selected_items'][$itemID])&&!empty($_POST['quantities'][$itemID])?$_POST['quantities'][$itemID]:0); // <-- Checks for quantities 
        $CombinedArray[$itemTitle] = $Qty;
    }
    print_r($CombinedArray);
}
?>
```

Would result in something like:

```
"Bread"=>0
"Coffee"=>44
"Egg"=>56
"Cake"=>0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is what I want.
Btw, `<input type='hidden' name='available_items[]' value="<?php echo $itemID; ?>" />` should be `<input type='hidden' name='available_items[<?php echo $itemID; ?>]' value="<?php echo $itemTitle; ?>" />`